# Disable QuickTime setting time in status bar to 9:41 for screen recording of iOS device

Tags: ios, video, quicktime

When you record a video of your iOS device QuickTime helpfully tidies up your status bar, including setting the time to 9:41.

This is great in many cases, but I have several apps which display the time in the app and so showing 9:41 in the status bar and the real time in the app is very jarring.

Does anyone know if it is possible to **turn off** the neat status? Maybe with some defaults setting or something?

Comment: For the time being I set a flag in the app so that it shows all times in the app to 9:41